# How to detect collision between a particle in particle system and Object3D in three.js?

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, collision, raycasting

I'm new to three.js. I created a particle system and the particles in the particle system keep moving around the scene. How do I detect when any particle hits an object (object loaded from an obj file) in the scene.

The particles do not move in a straight line.

Comment: Please include any relevant code so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: That will depend on the complexity of the model and the precision required. Your best bet is approximations, IE boxes, spheres, etc for geom, or a height map for terrain.. I do not think that Javascript is up to the job of real time particle mesh interaction on all but the most simple geometry. There could be a GPU solution bu that would be very scene specific.